# mapping a tictactoe board in javascript

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I'm creating a Tic Tac Toe solver algorithm. The idea is to iterate through each row, column and both diagonals and put them into a map in JavaScript. With that map I can run other logic to check for a winner and where that winner's position is.

I'm not building an actual TTT game nor am I writing any AI for now. My question is if there's a better way of achieving the same results without having to use two for loops to get the columns and second diagonals.

```js
let board = [
  ['x','o','x'],
  ['o','o','o'],
  ['o','o','x']
];

const mapper = board => {
  let map = {}, 
  d1 = [],
  d2 = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    let tmp = [];
    // get all rows
    map[`ROW${i}`] = board[i];

    // get second diagonals
    d2.push(board[i][board.length-1-i]);

    for (let j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
      // get all columns
      tmp.push(board[j][i]);

      // get first diagonals
      if (i === j) {
        d1.push(board[i][j])
      }
    }
    
    map[`COL${i}`] = tmp;
  }

  map[`DIA1`] = d1;
  map[`DIA2`] = d2;

  return map;
}

const checkForWinner = board => {
  return mapper(board);
}

checkForWinner(board);
```

Comment: hard code it (i.e. unroll the loops) and cross your fingers that the TTT board never changes. You know, like zip codes never changed and 2 digit years was good enough.

Answer (score 1):

### Not the board, store the moves

A TicTacToe board can be mapped to two 9bit numbers that represent each player's moves then the test for winning moves is just a simple bitwise test against the 8 possible combinations of move that are a win.

> My question is if there's a better way of achieving the same results without having to use two for loops to get the columns and second diagonals.

The following may be what you want

```
// top left is low bit, bottom right is high bit
// coord to bit pos is x + y * 3
// Bit positions on board
// 0,1,2
// 3,4,5
// 6,7,8


const board = [['x','o','x'], ['o','o','o'], ['o','o','x']];
const players = ["x","o"];
const winMoves = [448,56,7,292,146,73,273,84];

const getMoves = (board, player) => {
  var moves = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i ++){
     moves += board[i / 3 | 0][i % 3] === player ? 1 << i : 0;
  }
  return moves;
}
const checkWin = (board, player) =>{
  const moves = getMoves(board, player);
  return winMoves.some(win => (win & moves) === win);
}
if(!players.some(player => {
    if(checkWin(board, player)) { 
        console.log("Player " + player + " wins");
        return true;
    }
}){
  console.log("No winner");
}
```

### Complete game state in 18bits

If you look into the problem further you can reverse the board/moves relationship so that the board is created from two sets of moves. This means you can store the complete game state with only 2 9bit numbers and you would not have to examine the board to find the win

```
const move = (player, x, y) => player |= 1 << (x + y * 3);
const checkWin = moves => winMoves.some(win => (win & moves) === win);
const winMoves = [448,56,7,292,146,73,273,84];
var movesX = 0, movesO = 0; // moves for each player game start

// or from your example the moves would be
// x o x
// o o o
// o o x
movesX = 0b100000101;
movesO = 0b011111010;

// with
console.log(checkWin(movesX)); // >> false
console.log(checkWin(movesO)); // >> True
```